# Boost Multi Index: index based on list content

Tags: c++, boost

I'm new to Boost Multi Index container, and was wondering if it could solve in a more effecient way my problem, simplified thus:

```
struct A {
   int id;
}

struct B {
   int id;
   std::list<A> products;
}
```

Each A having a strictly unique ID, I want to be able with a single multi index container, be able to look for B.
By B's id, and by A's Id.

At the moment i'm working with nice std::map, and map linking A ids to B ids. 
So to say. It works fine enough. But, I'm having other parameters for such a look up and it's getting really nasty :)

EDIT:

As per comment request I'll elaborate somewhat:

I've Satellites, which in turn have many Transponders and many Sources. 
I want to be able to find a Satellite for a given Transponder id or Source id( which are indeed unique )

Sadly I don't have hand on Satellite struct, means, I can't alter it.

Briefly it looks like that :

```
struct Satellite {
 int norad_id;
 std::list<Transponder> transponders;
 std::list<Source> sources;
 ... some more data
}
```

What I want to do is simply search a whatever of Satellites, and find a Satellite having a specific transponder-, or source-, or norad id.

At the moment, I'm using 3 nice maps

```
std::map<int /*norad*/ ,Satellite> satellites;
std::map<int /*transponder  id*/, int/* norad */> transponder_to_satellite;
std::map<int /* source_id */,  int /* norad */ > source_to_satellite;
```

From the example @sehe provided, I see it would be somewhat easier if I were to spawn a relationnal struct. I guess I'll give it a try ... :)

Comment: You should make the sample real. As stated, a multimap or bimap would be plenty. "But, I'm having other parameters for such a look up" (what?). Be specific. Also, try not to maim type names, because that will make it impossible to spot the underlying XY problem

Answer (score 1):

In the absense of exact use cases, here' some suggestions to model the indices based on what you showed¹

```
struct Product {
int id;
};

struct Category {
int id;
};

struct ProductCategoryRelation {
    int productId;
    int categoryId;
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

using RelationTable = bmi::multi_index_container<
    ProductCategoryRelation,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct by_product>,
            bmi::member<ProductCategoryRelation, int, &ProductCategoryRelation::productId>
        >,
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct by_category>,
            bmi::member<ProductCategoryRelation, int, &ProductCategoryRelation::categoryId>
        >
    >
>;
```

You could also get quite smart with a composite key, which is versatile in `ordered_*` indexes:

```
using RelationTable = bmi::multi_index_container<
    ProductCategoryRelation,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct by_product>,
            bmi::composite_key<ProductCategoryRelation,
                bmi::member<ProductCategoryRelation, int, &ProductCategoryRelation::categoryId>,
                bmi::member<ProductCategoryRelation, int, &ProductCategoryRelation::productId>
            >
        >
    >
>;
```

Here's a small demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c06429599d04344)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/global_fun.hpp>
#include <list>

struct Product {
   int id;
};

struct Category {
   int id;
};

struct ProductCategoryRelation {
    int productId;
    int categoryId;
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

using RelationTable = bmi::multi_index_container<
    ProductCategoryRelation,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct compound>,
            bmi::composite_key<ProductCategoryRelation,
                bmi::member<ProductCategoryRelation, int, &ProductCategoryRelation::categoryId>,
                bmi::member<ProductCategoryRelation, int, &ProductCategoryRelation::productId>
            >
        >
    >
>;

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

int main() {
    RelationTable table {
        ProductCategoryRelation { 1, 7 },
        ProductCategoryRelation { 2, 7 },
        ProductCategoryRelation { 3, 7 },
        ProductCategoryRelation { 4, 6 },
        ProductCategoryRelation { 5, 6 },
        ProductCategoryRelation { 6, 6 },
        ProductCategoryRelation { 7, 5 },
        ProductCategoryRelation { 8, 5 },
        ProductCategoryRelation { 9, 5 },
    };

    // find all products in category 6:
    for (auto& rel : boost::make_iterator_range(table.get<compound>().equal_range(6)))
        std::cout << "Product " << rel.productId << " is in category " << rel.categoryId << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Product 4 is in category 6
Product 5 is in category 6
Product 6 is in category 6
```

---

¹ I crystal-balled the class names into something "realistic"

Comment: Edited my question, I thanks you for this example, I'll give it a try, but as said in my edit, I'm not allowed to edit the original struct. Which makes it somewhat more complicated to implement this strategy.